# Metric Tensor inside Earth

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor

Since Schwarzchild Metric is a vacuum solution (hence won't work inside earth), what metric do we use to describe gravity inside earth? What are the conditions to derive it?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/219897/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/290058/2451